Le mot « bagarrée » existe-t-il vraiment ? Si oui, comment l'utiliser ?
Dans plusieurs sources (e.g. Wiktionnaire), le mot « bagarrée » est attesté comme étant le participe passé féminin singulier du verbe bagarrer.
Or, je ne comprends pas comment utiliser ce mot dans une phrase, car, selon ma compréhension, le verbe « bagarrer » est intransitif (et donc son participe passé ne s'accorde pas en genre) et sa forme pronominale « se bagarrer » n'a pas de complément d'objet direct qui puisse justifier l'accord « bagarrée » du participe passé de ce verbe occasionnellement pronominal.
Ai-je une erreur dans mon raisonnement ? Y a-t-il une définition de « bagarrer » qui m'échappe ?
Une explication et un exemple d'utilisation de « bagarrée » seraient les bienvenus.

Se bagarrer est essentiellement (et non occasionnellement) pronominal, je pense que c'est là que le raisonnement a bloqué. J'ai quand même vérifié plusieurs sources pour confirmer ma mémoire. 1, 2, 3, 4 (p.2).

Bagarrer est un verbe intransitif, c'est à dire qu'il ne peut pas avoir de complément d'objet direct, on dit par exemple :

Il/elle a bagarré dur pour en arriver là où il est.

On ne peut pas dire :  « Il a bagarré sa chienne ». À partir du moment où on veut introduire un COD qui reçoit des coups dans la bagarre, il faut chercher un autre verbe qui accepte un COD, par exemple :

Il a battu sa chienne pour la dresser.
Oui, et il l'a bien battue1 !

On ne trouvera donc jamais la forme « bagarrée » dans cet emploi du verbe où l'affrontement est mental et où des coups physiques ne sont pas impliqués.
La seule occurrence d'un accord sur « bagarrer » est dans se bagarrer qui est un verbe dit essentiellement pronominal.
Au contraire de l'emploi intransitif du verbe « bagarrer » décrit plus haut, « se bagarrer » peut impliquer des coups physiques, reçus et donnés.
La règle est que le participe passé des verbes essentiellement pronominaux s’accorde toujours en genre et en nombre avec le sujet.
Accord du participe passé des verbes essentiellement pronominaux.
On peut donc trouver :

Elle s'est bagarrée avec sa sœur.
Ils se sont bagarrés à la sortie du collège.


Suite à la question sur le classement du verbe en essentiellement pronominal posée en commentaire par @Frank j'ajoute la sous-entrée du nom bagarre  du Dictionnaire historique de la  langue française (sld Alain Rey) :

En est dérivé ʙᴀɢᴀʀʀᴇʀ v.intr. et pron. (1905), de nos jours surtout utilisé à la forme pronominale pour « lutter, batailler pour vaincre », en sports et dans la vie courante.

Le verbe est donc une création récente, et à ce jour c'est son emploi comme verbe pronominal qui domine, ce qui peut expliquer le fait qu'il soit classé dans les verbes essentiellement pronominaux.   J'ajoute aussi que tous les tableaux de conjugaison le classe ainsi puisqu'ils font l'accord avec le sujet, par exemple Le Robert ou Bescherelle.

 1 Ceci est un exemple grammatical dans lequel il ne faut voir aucune animosité à l'égard de quiconque. L'idée d'animosité est intrinsèque au sens du verbe et chacun pourra remplacer le mot « chienne »  par une figure féminine de son choix, l'accord sera inchangé.

C'est vraiment un verbe essentiellement pronominal? Tu parles pourtant de bagarrer sans le pronom en tête de ta réponse.

@Frank bagarrer est un verbe intransitif.  Se bagarrer est un verbe essentiellement pronominal (et non occasionnellement pronominal, voir mon commentaire au PO).

OK, ça c'est une réitération de l'assertion de la pronominalité essentielle dudit verbe. Mais je ne comprends toujours pas. Si on peut donner un usage du verbe sans le pronom (comme tu le fais), que devient l'essentialité?

@Frank  Son classement en "essentiel" relève à mon avis du fait que bagarrer et se bagarrer ont des sens différents. Bagarrer ne s'emploie pas pour parler d'un échange de coups, on ne bagarre pas qn. Compare avec castagner, on peut castagner qn et se castagner, il y a ds les 2 cas échange de coups. Un verbe est essentiellement pronominal s'il existe uniquement à la forme pronominale ou si  son sens diffère quand il est à la forme pronominale, certains les appellent aussi v. pronominaux autonomes.

Amuser fonctionne de la même façon, Il amuse la galerie (divertir) Ils se sont amusés ensemble (jouer). S'amuser se classe aussi dan les pronominaux autonomes.

Ce n'est pas entièrement convaincant. Pour amuser et s'amuser je peux dire qu'il s'agit de se divertir dans les deux cas. Je veux bien, mais la justification devient un peu ténue pour moi. Ne serait-ce pas plutôt l'usage?

@Frank Pourquoi pas l'usage, oui bien sûr, c'est tout aussi possible. Ça ne change rien au fait qu'on écrit toujours elle s'est bagarrée et c'est bien avec le sujet que l'accord se fait.

Oui, je suis bien d'accord. A noter aussi que la règle devient alors identique avec celle sur l'accord du participe passé avec le sujet dans le cas de l'auxiliaire être, qui est nettement plus simple... C'est comme si ce verbe pronominal n'avait plus rien de spécial, dans ce cas.

Les sources n'ont vraiment rien pour être claires... L'entrée BAGARRÉE du Wiktionnaire dit que c'est le participe passé de BAGARRER (pas de SE BAGARRER)... L'entrée BAGARRER dit que BAGARRER c'est se battre et SE BAGARRER c'est combattre, sens assez près quand même... Votre hyperlien pour « essentiellement pronominal » ne parle pas du cas autonome et ne met pas l'accent, dans sa définition, sur le sens du verbe... Mais soit.

@NeedForHelp Je ne mentionne pas ce que « certains [ ] appellent aussi v. pronominaux autonomes. »  parce que c'est « certains », donc pas une appellation communément reprise. En grammaire il y a des écoles de pensée et pas une pensée unique, la grammaire n'est pas une science. Le wiktionnaire n'est pas une référence, chaque utilisateur présente à sa façon (et n'est pas toujours/souvent un expert) je viens de regarder, conjugaison de se bagarrer comporte des erreurs (comparer avec, par ex. celle du Robert).

@NeedForHelp Je disais que le wiktionnaire n'était pas toujours une référence, et ça se voit justement dans la conjugaison de se bagarrer : l'accord est fait au pluriel uniquement et le féminin est totalement ignoré, ce qui ne peut absolument pas se justifier d'un point de vue grammatical.  Certains crieraient au machisme.
